# How can I get items of local scope in nested list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find consecutive and identical elements in a list:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5]

new_list_1 = []
new_list_2 = []

def hello(x):
    for j, i in enumerate(x):
        try:
            if x[j] == x[j + 1] or x[j] == x[j-1]:
                new_list_1.append((i, j))
            else:
                new_list_2.append((i, j))
        except IndexError:
            if x[j]==x[j-1]:
                new_list_1.append((i, j))

print(hello(a))
print(new_list_1)
```

It's returning:

```
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14), (5, 15), (5, 16), (5, 17)]
```

But I want something like this:

```
[[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], [(2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)], [(1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14)], [(5, 15), (5, 16), (5, 17)]]
```

I don't want to use any external module like **itertools**' `chain` or `groupby`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why the arbitrary module restriction? Itertools is part of the standard library.

Comment: _"I don't want to use any external module like itertools chain or groupby , How can i achieve this ?"_ - Why not? Is this simply for practice?

Comment: How do you determine which pairs are in each list?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators)-based approach:

```
def indexed_groups(lst):
    ret_val, crnt = [], None
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x != crnt:  # for every new item
            if len(ret_val) > 1:  # check if there is a group to yield
                yield ret_val
            ret_val, crnt = [], x  # reset group and current
        ret_val.append((x, i))  # collect (item, index) pairs
    if len(ret_val) > 1:  # check last group
        yield ret_val

>>> list(indexed_groups(a))
[[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)], 
 [(2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)], 
 [(1, 12), (1, 13), (1, 14)], 
 [(5, 15), (5, 16), (5, 17)]]
```

Comment: can you please read my last line in question ? you can get downvote for this.

Comment: Sure thing, edited it to work without any imports ;)